Node js ejs variable not define issue
i am mern stack developer and i don't have any experience in this field. I have tried all method to solve the below problem but it gives error
my template file is
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- Fontawesome -->
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/42a182743f.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/uploadPhoto.css" />
    <title>Upload Profile Photo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- nav-bar -->
    <%- include("../partials/navbar") %>

    <div class="form-container">
      <!-- icon -->
      <h1>Upload Profile photo</h1>
      <p>
        <!-- upload icon -->
      </p>
      <small class="error">
        <% if (uploadedImage) { %>
          <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
          <%= uploadedImage %>
        <% } %>
      </small>
      <form action="/api/v1/users/profile-photo-upload?_method=PUT" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="email">Select Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="profile" id="image" />
        <button type="submit">
          <i class="fas fa-upload"></i>
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- footer -->
    <%- include("../partials/footer") %>
  </body>
</html>


and my server file is,
app.put("/profile",async (req,res,next)=>{
    try {
        //check if no file if upload
        if(!req.file) return next(appErr("No profile image is uploaded"));
        //find the user to be updated
        const userID = req.session.userAuth;
        const findUser = await User.findById(userID);
        //if user not found
        if(!findUser) return next(appErr("User not found",403));
        //update profile photo
        const newUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(userID,{
            profileImage: req.file.path
        },{
            new: true
        });
         //if new file is uploaded then delete old one
         if(req.file && findUser.profileImage !== undefined){
            const public_id = extractPublicId(findUser.profileImage);
            cloudinary.uploader.destroy(public_id)
        };
      
        res.locals.uploadedImage = "Image Uploaded";
        res.render("users/uploadProfilePhoto");
    } catch (error) {
        return next(appErr(error.message));
    }
};);

so the problem is that every time i access uploadedImage in template file it gives error uploadedImage is undefined but when i use res.locals.uploadedImage in middleware it perfectly worked
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    if(req.session.userAuth){
        res.locals.uploadedImage = "File Uploaded";
    }else{
        res.locals.uploadedImage = null;
    }
    next();
});

can someone explain me why res.locals.uploadedImage work  with middleware and not work with route and please provide some solution?
i want the solution of the above code and want to know that why res.locals.uploadedImage works perfectly with middleware but gives error when it is used in a route

I don't understand neither why it doesn't work, it should. But what you can try, is to pass the uploadedImage variable as an argument to the render function like let uploadedImage = "Image uploaded"; res.render("users/uploadProfilePhoto", {uploadedImage: uploadedImage}); or just res.render("users/uploadProfilePhoto", {uploadedImage: "Image uploaded"}); to test if it works this way.

To answer your question, please try to execute the following two statements in an Express server application either in a route handler or in a middleware.
As the output below shows, these are the two javascript objects available in the application and response objects in every Express app. As javascript is a dynamic language, the application code can add more properties to it, as you have done - res.locals.uploadedImage.
The point is that : these two objects are accessible in templates. As a result, all of its properties are available in templates. The notable point is that these properties are freely available without referencing through the respective objects, it is accessible by the statement like this - <%= title %>
Now regarding the error you get, app.locals object will be available throughout the life of the Express application instance. However the life span of a response.locals object is relatively short. It lives only for a specific request-response cycle. So when you define it in the middleware, then it lives and it works, and when you do not define it, it does not exist and then the template results in the error.
  console.log(res.locals);
  console.log(app.locals);

The server console will print as below:
[Object: null prototype] {}
[Object: null prototype] {
  settings: {
    'x-powered-by': true,
    ...
    ...
    env: 'development',
    ...
    views: '/Users/jf/Documents/JF/so/78718290/views',
    ...
  }
}

Citation:
Express4. What's the difference between app.locals, res.locals and req.app.locals?

Hi, Is this answer found useful to you? In case of any clarifications you may require, kindly comment.
